# Twitter4j automatically reconnection policy

Tags: twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I'm testing twitter4j to retrieve status filtered stream.
All works fine but I'm not able to find any information about the policy
twitter4j uses to reconnect in case of disconnection.

I can manage this event in this way:

```
public void onException(Exception ex) {
                if (ex instanceof TwitterException){
                    TwitterException tw_ex = (TwitterException) ex;
                    //TODO: manage all disconnect causes
                }else{
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

...but does twitter4J automatically try to reconnect to the server?
If yes, what about the policy twitter4j use to retry the connection?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes. It automatically tries to reconnect *infinitely*, following some increasing delay